# Sobre funções MySQLi

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma dúvida quanto algumas *funções* do *MySQLi*

No modo convencional faríamos assim:

```
public function Numrows($sql) {
      return mysqli_num_rows($sql);
}
```

E como estou utilizando `extends mysqli` estou fazendo isto:

```
public function dbNumRows($Query) {

    $sql = parent::prepare($Query);

    return $sql->num_rows();
}
```

Qual a maneira mais correta de retornar números de linhas usando PHP Orientado com a `class extends mysqli`?

Classe completa da conexão

```
<?php

class Connect extends mysqli {

    public $db_connection, $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db_hostname = DB_HOSTNAME;
        $this->db_username = DB_USERNAME;
        $this->db_password = DB_PASSWORD;
        $this->db_database = DB_DATABASE;

        $this->connectMe();
    }

    private function connectMe() {
        $this->db_connection = @$this->connect($this->db_hostname, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_database);

        if ($this->connect_error) {
            die("Falha na tentativa de se conectar com o servidor: " . $this->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function dbExecute($Query) {
        $Result = $this->query($Query);

        if ($this->error) {
            die("Erro no comando: $Query");
        }

        return $Result;
    }

    public function dbNumRows($Query) {
       return $this->prepare($Query)->num_rows();
    }

}
```

Att.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está herdando da classe `mysqli` todos os métodos disponíveis estarão na sua nova classe. Não precisa criar novos métodos para isso:

```
<?php

class MeuBanco extends mysqli{

    // ...

}

$db = new MeuBanco();
$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM test')->num_rows();
```

Se quiser utilizar os métodos do `mysqli` dentro da sua classe não precisa utilizar `parent::`, pode utilizar o `$this` como se fosse um método da própria classe.

```
public function dbNumRows($query) 
{
    return $this->prepare($query)->num_rows();
}
```

Outra forma é editar sua função pra receber o [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php):

```
public function dbNumRows(mysqli_result $query) 
{
    return $query->num_rows;
}
```

Note que `num_rows` é uma propriedade de `mysqli_result`, logo isso deve funcionar também:

```
<?php

$query = $Connect->dbExecute("SELECT * FROM oop_usuarios"); 
$num = $query->num_rows;
```

Comment: Eu já tentei usar como você recomendou mas tenho como retorno dois erros veja: `Warning: mysqli::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\wamp\www\oop\modules\class\Connect.class.php on line 35` o outro erro: `Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\oop\modules\class\Connect.class.php on line 35` está assim meu método `public function dbNumRows($Query) {
       return $this->prepare($Query)->num_rows();
    }`

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves você está passando um argumento incorreto. O método `prepare` espera uma string, e você está passando outra coisa.

Comment: Estou passando uma variável que é o parâmetro que estou passando aqui veja: `$query = $Connect->dbExecute("SELECT * FROM oop_usuarios"); `
`$num= $Connect->dbNumRows($query );` estou no meu trabalho agora quando eu chegar em casa eu vejo o que posso fazer, se você tiver alguma dica...

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves dessa maneira está errada. Poste sua classe de conexão completa na pergunta.

Comment: foi adicionado no tópico.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves Tente `$db->dbNumRows('SELECT * FROM oop_usuarios');`. Passe somente a query `SELECT * FROM oop_usuarios`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24049/discussion-between-guilherme-alves-and-gmsantos).

Comment: Sim deste jeito da certo, mas queria pegar pelo parâmetro passado!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que está passando a query já feita para o método de classe. Isto está incorreto. Está misturando chamada procedural com orientada a objeto.

Uma vez a query feita você só deve utilizar ela para extrair os dados, e não passar para outro construtor. Mesmo em uma classe herdada.

A função `dbNumRows` não é necessária e pode ser retirada,

```
$cn = Connect();
$query = $cn->dbExecute('SELECT * from table'); // A query está pronta
$nr = $query->num_rows; // Lendo número de linhas da query
```

Ref.: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Note que nem o `dbExecute` é necessário, mas deixei considerando que pode fazer algo diferente da execução padrão de `query`.

Se vai utilizar prepare, há um pouco mais de código, mas mantém o mesmo processo de não ficar criando o mesmo objeto, crie um e utilize as entradas e saídas de dados dele.

**Edição 2015-05-24:**
Exemplo de classe descendente da classe mysqli:

Instalar o XAMPP (testado com o xampp-win32-5.6.8-0-VC11-installer.exe);
Criar um arquivo PHP e copiar nele o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php
/*
 * Estende a classe mysqli com uma função para fazer uma query a uma tabela
 * específica.
 */
class MinhaConexao extends mysqli {
    function MinhaQuery($filtro) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cds';
        if ($filtro != '') {
            $sql = $sql . ' WHERE ' . $filtro;
        }
        return parent::query($sql);
    }
}

$cn = new MinhaConexao('localhost', 'root', '', 'cdcol');

if (isset($_POST['from'])) {
    $from = intval($_POST['from']);
} else {
    $from = 1990;
}

if (isset($_POST['to'])) {
    $to = intval($_POST['to']);
} else {
    $to = 2005;
}
?><html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste com classe herdada do MySQLi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php print($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Ano de <input type="text" name="from" value="<?php echo $from; ?>"/> a <input type="text" name="to" value="<?php echo $to; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
        $query = $cn->MinhaQuery('(jahr >= ' . $from . ') AND (jahr <= ' . $to . ')');
        ?>
        Quantidade: <?php print_r($query->num_rows); ?>
        <?php
        while ($r = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            print('<p>');
            print_r($r);
            print('</p>');
        }
        $query->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html><?php
$cn->close();
?>
```

Abrir o painel de controle do XAMPP, ativar os servidores Apache e MySQL e acessar o arquivo criado com o navegador.

Comment: É eu não consigo retornar o número de linhas nem que a vaca tussa! Você teria algum tutorial semelhante ao que estou tentando fazer?

Comment: Não tenho tutorial, mas criei um exemplo completo de uma classe e uso da mesma. Nem me preocupei em segurança, o foco é só a classe e seu uso, no modelo oop. Noque que a variável query não é passada como parâmetro, ela tem suas propriedades e funções, e é o que deve ser utilizado.